# Is there any way to fix this?

Tags: post-production, production, fix

I recorded this piece of audio that seems to have this continuous periodic loss of volume.
I have at my disposal the full Adobe suite and Izotope RX10 but I;m not too familiar with its tools. Any way to fix this?
[Audiofile](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/a1qq7krii1ireyqnaui1h/h?dl=0&rlkey=b001hrnmmam5d6oppomfirzji)

[image: Spectral in RX10]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but I don't see it as being fixable - you literally have nothing in the gaps to boost even in the otherwise loudest portions, only this odd little 'bounce' which happens every time.

I'm no electronics guy, but that bounce makes me think of a capacitor 'recovering' after rapid discharge - it looks a bit like a vehicle shock absorber's recovery after hitting a bump;)

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I don't even think it pauses in the gaps - It's not English, so I can't be sure.

Comment: @n00dles - Yeah, other than this odd repeating dropout, it sounds kind of echoed - idk whether that's some mic/speaker feedback on a skype call or what .. I can't tell what's being said either so I've nothing to hang onto when listening. [Plus, I kind of went straight for the visual analysis of what may be left in the gaps, without spending much time at all listening to it.]

Comment: It is a strange one. A ~200 Hz low shelf cut makes it more audible, but yeah, a lost cause really.

Comment: @n00dles - I must admit, as soon as I saw that single identical wave in every drop I didn't even bother listening to it a second time ;)

Comment: So what is crazy it's that it might be related to a low 9V battery inside of the microphone.

Comment: Maybe - it's somewhat reminiscent of [motorboating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorboating_(electronics)) but I don't have enough electronics background to really know.