# Is this normal for a RODE NTG 5?

Tags: microphone, noise, power, camera, self-noise

I bought a used NTG 5 and am trying to gauge if I got a dud or this behaviour is normal.
[This Video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/plscwn4dus1enpi/NTG5%20Problem.mov?dl=0) is self explanatory, but basically, whenever I try and use my NTG 5 with my Pocket 4k I get this high speed periodic noise, which does not happen with any other mic as illustrated in the video (I tested an NTG 2 and a MKH 416).

This noise presents itself every time that the camera is not externally powered, and sometimes even if the camera is externally powered.

**The NTG 5 works fine on an external recorder like the zoom H6.**

I'm wondering if it could be that it is very sensitive to "bad" phantom and behaves abnormally with the camera, or if it's a sign of worse things to come.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Is this related to https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/52097/is-there-any-way-to-fix-this ?

Comment: No, I'm the same guy but two different microphones with two different problems.